# Update product name programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

- I'm trying to programatically update configurable product name and keep other product data unchanged.
- The store has 6 store views.
- Each store view has unique name - all of them need changing.

I'm using this code:

```
...
$product = $this->productRepository->get('111111111');
$product->setName('New Name');
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

It updates the name but also removes the product from other storeviews (keeps for the default store view only) and removes all product variations.

Questions:

1. How do I update product name for each store view separately?
2. Why Product Repository's save method removes stuff + how to prevent it?

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just try with below solutions,

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager){
    $this->action = $action;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function saveProductAttribute(){
    $id = '1'; //product id
    $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore(); 
    $storeId = $store->getId();  // Get Store ID
    $this->action->updateAttributes([$id],['name' => 'test1'],$storeId);
}
```

Comment: can we update with product object?